# Grammatical Error: He is such a man who is liked by everyone

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically correct?

> He is such a man who is liked by everyone.

Comment: I am guessing that what you mean is, "He is the type of man who is liked by everyone." Is that correct?

Comment: "such" with the meaning of "a member of a class" is more often used after the description than before because "such" in this sense needs the class to be defined or understood first. For instance "There are men who are liked by everyone: he is such a man." Another use of "such" is as an expression of degree, for example "He is _such_ a pleasant man _that_ he is liked by everyone." But this is using "such" in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not grammatically correct. Here are your alternatives, assuming a conversation in which this type of man is being discussed, for example:

*There are some men who are universally liked...*

> He is such a man,  one who is liked by everyone.
>
> He is such a man, one liked by everyone.

Or with [ellipsis] in a disjunct clause:

> He is such a man— <sup>[he is one]</sup> who is liked by everyone.
>
> He is such a man— <sup>[he is]</sup> liked by everyone.

Or :

> He is a man who is liked by everyone.
>
> He is a man liked by everyone.

Comment: There are other alternatives, see my request for clarification above.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK  It looks to me like a standard grammar-book exercise on how to use **such a...** with a relative clause. With "the type" you've added an entirely unrelated alternative.

Comment: Well, if grammar books give examples containing incorrect grammar without making the error clear then I have no confidence in such books. Let's see if the OP clarifies.

Comment: Whatever the case, "the type" is from out in left field, as we baseball fans say. Why not also "the sort" and "the kind"?

Comment: I'm not sure why we're arguing about this. I could indeed have used 'sort' or 'kind'. The fact is that I was using my experience of various *translation* forums to guess what the problem might be. I did however make it clear that I was guessing. You and I cannot resolve this. We must wait to see if the OP accepts your answer and/or replies to my comment.

Comment: You're criticizing my answer for being incomplete and I'm criticizing your comment for missing the point. That's why we're arguing about this.  I think you took things in the wrong direction with your comment about grammar books.

Comment: @Romano - I have no more to say on the subject.

Comment: "He is such a man ***as*** is liked by everyone."

Comment: @Araucaria. Aye, that he be.